# DiskPart executing only part of script withour giving any error?

Tags: cmd.exe, script, c#, diskpart

I'm creating DiskPart script in C#. It's saved in TXT file with ASCII encoding set. I need to create 3 partitions: EFI, MSR and Primary one. Script is intended to prepare disk for WIM image deployment. But script creates EFI partition and just exits, without assigning drive letter or doing anything else.

Here are screenshots:
DiskPart output after running script:
[image: DiskPart output after running script]

Actual changes on disk:
[image: Actual changes on disk]

This is my script:

```
select disk 2
clean
create partition efi size=300
assign letter=s
create partition msr size=16
create partition primary
assign letter=t
```

That's how I generate it (C#):

```
            DPScript = "";
            DPScript += "select disk " + SelectedDiskId;
            DPScript += "\r\nclean";
            DPScript += "\r\ncreate partition efi size=300";
            // Here DiskPart exits with no reason
            DPScript += "\r\nassign letter=s";
            DPScript += "\r\ncreate partition msr size=10";
            DPScript += "\r\ncreate partition primary";
            DPScript += "\r\nassign letter=t";
            MessageBox.Show(DPScript, "DiskPart script");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(".\\DPScript.txt", DPScript, Encoding.ASCII);
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/k diskpart.exe /s .\\DPScript.txt"
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

Thank you for any help, I'm getting mad with it.

Comment: Here’s what I would do: Remove the next command that would have run: `assign letter=s`. Try again. See what happens. // It may not be possible to use `assign` with an EFI System Partition. Furthermore, you are not formatting the partitions.

Comment: @DanielB As far as I know you can't assign a drive-letter to a partition without a filesystem on it. Because the drive-letter actually assigns to the filesystem. Not the partition itself. 
So it silently fails at the assign command. Another thing: After CLEAN it is always a good idea to explicitly set the partitiontable to either MBR or GUID as required. This script would fail if used on a MBR disk...